# video API iphone

Tags: iphone, video

I  want to play H.264 video streamed from network. To play video iphone provides the media player API.  Does anyone one aware of any documented or undocumented API for decoding and playing single video frame?

Answer (score 0):

Is it Live video or on demand ?

If live the only way is to use iPhone OS 3 with MediaPlayer.
take a look at the discussions group from apple there is some interesting thread.